# why is the if statement not working in js

Tags: javascript

```js
window.addEventListener("keyup", addkey);

function addkey(){
  var x = event.which || event.keyCode;
  var wkey = 0;
  var op = 0;
  
  if(x == 87){
   wkey += 1;
  }
  if(wkey == 1 && op == 0){
   alert("your doing good!");
   op = op + 1;
  }
 }
```

What im trying to get to happen here is getting the alert statement to run once and only once but i cant get it to work either way. I tried using a true or false numberical system (the op variable) but that dident work either. What i see happening is when the code runs and the keyup event fires the wkey variable updates once and stays 1 even know it should be going up a numeral each time the w key is pressed. Anyway i am making this code to go along with a tutorial for the game im making. Any and all suggestions i am open to.

Comment: shouldn't it be `function addkey(event)` ?

Comment: Don't rely on the global `event` property, that only works in some browsers. Instead, change to `function addkey(event) {` to ensure you are capturing the event that is passed to your handler in all browsers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because you re-initialize `op` to `0` every time the function gets called. You can simply delcare `op` outside of `addkey` and it will work:

```js
window.addEventListener("keyup", addkey);
var op = 0;
var wkey = 0;

function addkey(event){
    var x = event.which || event.keyCode;
    
    if(x == 87){
        wkey += 1;
    }
    if(wkey == 1 && op == 0){
        alert("your doing good!");
        op += 1;
    }
}
```

You'll also need to pull the declaration of `wkey` out of the function if you want to successfully count how many times it was pressed.

Comment: He actually wants to count how many times the W key is pressed, so he cannot remove wkey, he doesn't just want the popup every time the W key is pressed, but instead the popup first time then every other time wkey is increased by one without showing the popup - counting how many times W was pressed.

Comment: @Arber Sylejmani You're completely right. Seems like my brain isn't fully awake any more. I should probably go to sleep.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you define `wkey` and `op` on each function run, you should define them out of the function, to make it work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Each time the function is called,

`wkey` gets set to `0`,

and then `1` is added,

so it will always end up being equal to `1`

Try defining `wkey` as `0` outside of the function.

Or having

```
if(wkey == null) var wkey = 0;
```

instead.

If you use this method `op` is unnecessary. (Unless of course you're using it's value elsewhere.)